# Custom URL in get method for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, seo, getmethod

I had add this form in homepage of my theme

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <label>NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
    <button>GET</button>
</form>

<?php

 if (isset($_GET['name'])){

    $name = $_GET['name'];

  echo "hello".$name;}
?>
```

and here I am getting url at top is

> example.com/?name=google

and i want custom url as

> example.com/name/google

so what should i do to get custom URL by get method?

Comment: i had tried using .htaccess but didnt work...

it works well for site without wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Permalink to postname wp automatically convert it

Comment: i did that but search query shows as i mentioned above

Comment: Use Add rewrite rule function

Comment: More help visit here
http://www.yellowblog.tk/index.php/2015/09/18/custom-url-in-get-method-for-wordpress/

Comment: yes but at present its showing error.. Error 404 Not Found Oops! We couldn’t find this Page. Please check your URL or use the search form below.

Comment: Change peramalink settings then change back to your permalink setting

Comment: yes it worked by changing that but now i want to make that changes as mentioned in your blog

Answer (score 0):

Go to Permalink settings in wordpress `wp-admin`. From there, select the option custom type or post type according to your requirements.

Comment: i did that but search query shows as i mentioned above